# Vaadin: How do I get rid of vite?

Tags: vaadin

The description of "Vite" was tempting and I was stupid enough to enable this new feature. Since then I am stuck with endless UI recompile loops! I.e. each time after I logged into my application the frontend gets recompiled AGAIN and the application restarts. ||-(

Disabling Vite in the lower right control-dialog is not accepted, it remains activated. How do I get rid of this unbaked feature again?

This is using Vaadin 23.1.7 and Java 17.

Comment: Would you try with 23.2.0 (already in Maven central, official release later today) and see if the issue reproduces there? As mentioned below, no feature flag needed there. If the issue reproduces with 23.2, we really need to get this fixed and it would help to get more details to track this down. Then we'd want to know is your app Spring Boot, plain servlet or Java EE or what, possible hints from server and browser console.

Comment: How did you enable it? Is it still active after reverting this change?

Comment: > How did you enable it? I enabled it in the lower right corner Vaadin dialog under "Experimental Features". And I can (try to) switch it off there as often as I want: it stays activated.

Comment: Did you get the issue reproduced with 23.2.0 ? If so, it would be great if you could go and create an issue in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues and attach all possible logs/errors from both server and the browser.

Answer (score 8):

In Vaadin 23.1 you can remove the feature flag by deleting it from `src/main/resources/vaadin-featureflags.properties`.

Note that Vaadin 23.2 uses Vite by default. If you want to continue using Webpack going forward, you need to instead add this feature flag to the properties file:

```
com.vaadin.experimental.webpackForFrontendBuild=true
```